# How to embed power map in asp.net c# pragmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, maps

I have an excel sheet and it contains the following values

```
Code    State        Value
AK      Alaska       201254
AL      Alabama      52020
AR      Arkansas     545041
AZ      Arizona      630.63
CA     California   623520
```

I want to bind this values to Excel Power map pragmatically. How can I do this in asp.net using C#? I need to embed excel power map into my aspx page.

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/16101a/getting-started-with-microsoft-power-map-for-excel/    in this link they are directly showing in excel but i want to do this programatically.   asp.net with c#   .  i want to bind this values through codebehind and need to embed excel power map into my web page

Comment: is anyone else to help